# Sync music from iPad to a Windows machine

Tags: itunes, ipad

My Windows laptop died and I now have a new one.
My iPad was synced from my old laptop and so has all my music.

I assume that the default for iTunes would be to sync the new, empty library into the iPad and I lose everything.

How do I load my music **from** the iPad into my new laptop?

Can I also save the associated metadata - the date when last played etc? Can I also recover play lists?

Comment: music is not designed to sync from a device back to a computer - the computer is essentially the master, the iDevice the slave. You need a third party app to do it - some listed on the linked question, inclusing one for Windows.

Comment: The linked response is from 2012, so I assume that there will be newer software that will also do this.

Comment: Did you try the solutions listed in the other question?

Comment: @Tetsujin Music is music. If Apple have adopted a policy of forcing users to sync their music only from a computer down to an iPad, then that is another matter. So, yes, I assume that I will need a non-Apple solution.

Comment: Music is music - sure it is, but *purchased* music is *purchased* music. If you bought it all from the iTunes Store, then there is no issue re-accessing it from the Store on the computer or any other device with the same Apple ID. If you acquired it from elsewhere, then there is nothing forcing Apple to assist you. It has been this way since iTunes was released, nearly 20 years ago. They are also under no compunction to be responsible for you not having backed up your computer, in case of disaster.

Comment: @nohillside Not yet. I was hoping for a little more feedback on current solutions. The iExplorer software may have been a possible solution 9 years ago, but there may be other more effective solutions. I get one chance to recover the music, so I do hope for some feedback from somebody else who has done this fairly recently.

Comment: I never assumed that Apple would help me - hence my interest in "other" solutions. Of course I also have backups, which I will resort to if other routes fail. However, it would be very much better if I could simply recover what I **already have** on the iPad.